# SQL get two columns side by side one multiple value one unique value

Tags: sql, sqlyog

My problem is little unqiue, I tried finding but did not find desired answer,

I have two columns in my database, one is a and b consider "A" having ids and "B" having colors, now I am achieving half of what I want, is When I try to look for B column the ids repeat for example

```
1 Black
1 Black
2 Blue
2 Blue
2 Blue
3 White
```

now all I want is getting these columns and getting another two columns added to the same query that then show unqiue of column "A" and its color for example;

```
A B       C
1 Black   1 Black
1 Black   2 Blue
2 Blue    3 White
2 Blue
2 Blue
3 White
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange thing to want to do, but you can use window functions:

```
select t.a, t.b, tg.a as c, tg.b as d
from (select a, b, row_number() over (order by a, b) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t left join
     (select a, b, row_number() over (order by a, b) as seqnum
      from t
      group by a, b
     ) tg
     on t.seqnum = tg.seqnum;
```

Window functions are available starting in MySQL 8.0

Comment: Great, do you know how to achieve it on mysql 5 ?